# In PHP, why I am able to access non-static method in a static way?

Tags: php, static

In the following code, nonStatic() is not a static method. Even then I am able to access it without creating an object (in a static way). Could anyone please help me in understanding as this is not possible in other languages like Java?

```
<?php
class MyClass
{
    function nonStatic() {
        echo "This can be printed";
    }
}
MyClass::nonStatic(); // This can be printed
```

Comment: because OO concepts were bolted onto PHP as an afterthought?  Seriously, PHP, is not a model for OOP study.

Comment: You can call it statically as long as it doesn't include instance references (`$this`).  Not sure if you'll get warnings under `E_STRICT` (I would hope you do).

Comment: I do not agree this is a duplicate since this question contains better explanations at least

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure, probably some PHP magic (it's a bit like that sometimes), but you shouldn't do it.

Read more here http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

They also show a similar example, but note:

Calling non-static methods statically generates an E_STRICT level warning meaning this magic ability may disappear in future versions. So don't do it :)

Comment: Generally, PHP tries to, if possible, not crash and burn if unnecessary. In his example, nothing non-static is done, and because of that, the method is effectively static. The other way to think about it is static is a way to get php to check to make sure you didn't make a call to $this since the method is intended to be used statically - which is what all the other languages do anyway. It's just a construct. PHP compiles and executes at once, since it is a script language, so it has greater flexibility and makes turning this normally fatal error into a warning - possible.

Answer (score 6):

It's allowed, **but** it generates an `E_STRICT` warning:

```
Error #: 2048, Error: Non-static method MyClass::nonStatic() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context
```

In the earlier OO implementations of PHP this was silently allowed, but better practices have since been adopted.

The opposite works without a hitch though:

```
class Test
{
    function foo()
    {
        echo $this->bar();
    }

    static function bar()
    {
        return "Hello world\n";
    }
}

$x = new Test;
$x->foo();
```

This prints `Hello world`.

Answer (score 3):

It seems as though the developers of PHP didn't see any value in disallowing static access of non-static methods. This is just one of those idiosyncratic features of PHP that doesn't really serve a purpose. It certainly is bad programming practice to call a non-static method statically, but in PHP it is possible.  Maybe in a future version of PHP they will disallow this, but for now, it's just part of the language.

**Edit:**

<strike>Thankfully, the opposite is not allowed - you cannot call a static method from an object context.</strike> As Jack pointed out below, you **can** call a static method from an object context - hardly a best practice in the OOP paradigm, but it's allowed.

Comment: The opposite *is* actually allowed; not sure whether that's good or bad though ;-)

Comment: Thanks for alerting me to that, Jack! I've updated my comment.