# Using the :: operator on an object

Tags: php

Recently I've found interesting usage of code and I didn't know that it's possible. Can someone explain or give me manual page with explanation why the code below works? I understand `::` can be used to reflect methods from parent, static etc. or to access static fields/methods but with reference `$this` it seems weird mostly because method `a()` is not static

```
class Test
{
   private function a()
   {
      echo 'a works';
   }

   public static function c()
   {
      echo 'c works';
   }

   public function b()
   {
        $this::a(); // this is weird
        $this::c(); // also this
        $this->a(); // normal usage
        self::a();  // as expected
        static::a(); // same as above
        Test::c();  // as expected
   }
}


(new Test)->b();
```

I've tried to find some information on my own but with no luck.

**Edit:**

I'm aware what `::` is also I know it will throw warning if E_STRICT is enabled.

Comment: offtopic: just because you can, it doesn't mean you should. This is a perfect way to make your code unreadable.

Comment: It's obvious I won't use it but I want to know how's that possible.

Comment: @KyleE4K can you explain why? :) In my opinion if you wan to access method or class of object inside the class `$this` as reference to current object is *normal usage*

Comment: The only legitimate use I can see of `$this::a()` would be if you are working with dynamic classes and don't want to use reflection to find out if a method is static or not. Would lead to some really hard to understand code though.

Comment: If you're aware that non-static methods _can be_ called via static de-reference, I don't understand what's the question is about. In short: yes, it seems to be weird. But - yes, it is allowed in PHP an generates warnings. What else could be a better explanation?

Comment: There is an example for it in the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.class.this

Comment: @TobiasXy that explains a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of PHP 5.3, you can use a variable to reference the class with the `::` operator. [The manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php) only shows usages in which the variable is a string, however it is in fact possible to also use an object in its place; the class referenced is then the class the object is an instance of. There's an example buried in the manual for `static`: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php#language.oop5.static.properties.

So, all these resolve to the same thing:

```
$foo = new Foo;
$foo::bar();

$foo = 'Foo';
$foo::bar();

Foo::bar();
```

The methods will always be called statically; for methods which are already `static` this works as expected, [while for non-static methods an `E_STRICT` notice will be raised.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10392713/in-php-why-i-am-able-to-access-non-static-method-in-a-static-way)

This is mostly for convenience as far as I gather; you already have an object of a specific class, now you want to reference some static item of that class – just use the object you already have. This also allows for some more dynamic behaviour with subclassing. E.g.:

```
$foo = new SomeClassWithAVeryLongName;
$foo->bar($foo::BAZ); // much more concise than repeating SomeClassWithAVeryLongName::
```

Comment: So from what I understand it's all about the possibility of calling non static method in static context am I right?

Comment: That depends on what "it" is about. There are two separate issues really: 1) What does `$var::` do? – See above. 2) Why can you call non-static methods statically? – Because PHP; just please don't actually do it.

Comment: I understand it know I wasn't aware of the possibility to call non static method in static context in PHP.